# merge two states into one in react native

Tags: react-native, merge, state

hi everyone i have a question about react native. How do I merge two states into one? if for example I have:

```
this.state.post=[{"author": "167635", "authorName": "willy il coyote", "comment": undefined}, {"author": "167635", "authorName": "willy il coyote", "comment": undefined}, {"author": "139594", "authorName": "ao", "comment": "ccc "}, {"author": "142494", "authorName": "Ao", "comment": "Ravioli "},{"author": "5555", "authorName": "Mark", "comment": undefined},{"author": "7777", "authorName": "Jenny", "comment": undefined},{"author": "2222", "authorName": "Heley", "comment": undefined},{"author": "0000", "authorName": "Pott", "comment": undefined},{"author": "6666", "authorName": "Helen", "comment": undefined},{"author": "1234", "authorName": "Gess", "comment": undefined}]
this.state.post_update=[{"author": "uuuu", "authorName": "xxx", "comment": undefined}, {"author": "777", "authorName": "hhhhh", "comment": undefined}]
```

now I want to create an array of size 10 which contains the union of post_update and post.
But I want to show first the post_update posts and then in the remaining places I put post_update. So i want this output:

```
this.state.new_state=[{"author": "uuuu", "authorName": "xxx", "comment": undefined}, {"author": "777", "authorName": "hhhhh", "comment": undefined},{"author": "167635", "authorName": "willy il coyote", "comment": undefined}, {"author": "167635", "authorName": "willy il coyote", "comment": undefined}, {"author": "139594", "authorName": "ao", "comment": "ccc "}, {"author": "142494", "authorName": "Ao", "comment": "Ravioli "},{"author": "5555", "authorName": "Mark", "comment": undefined},{"author": "7777", "authorName": "Jenny", "comment": undefined},{"author": "2222", "authorName": "Heley", "comment": undefined},{"author": "0000", "authorName": "Pott", "comment": undefined}]
```

How can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge using the spread operator.

```
const postMerge =[...post_update, ...post];
```

```js
const post=[{"author": "167635", "authorName": "willy il coyote", "comment": undefined}, {"author": "167635", "authorName": "willy il coyote", "comment": undefined}, {"author": "139594", "authorName": "ao", "comment": "ccc "}, {"author": "142494", "authorName": "Ao", "comment": "Ravioli "},{"author": "5555", "authorName": "Mark", "comment": undefined},{"author": "7777", "authorName": "Jenny", "comment": undefined},{"author": "2222", "authorName": "Heley", "comment": undefined},{"author": "0000", "authorName": "Pott", "comment": undefined},{"author": "6666", "authorName": "Helen", "comment": undefined},{"author": "1234", "authorName": "Gess", "comment": undefined}];
const post_update=[{"author": "uuuu", "authorName": "xxx", "comment": undefined}, {"author": "777", "authorName": "hhhhh", "comment": undefined}]; 

const postMerge =[...post_update, ...post];

console.log(postMerge);
```